# How to seam seal Tyvek?

Tags: backpacking, ultralight, diy, tyvek

Tyvek generally comes in 4' and 5' wide sheets.  To make a suitable tarp, footprint, groundcloth, etc. I will need to sew together a couple of sheets.  How do I seam seal the Tyvek to prevent leaking at the joint?  ([Assuming I have determined what kind of Tyvek to buy](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/what-kind-of-tyvek-is-suitable-for-footprint-material))

Comment: I used GE's Silicone Gel II to seal seams on my RayWay tarp, and it works great.  I have no idea if it would stick to Tyvek or not, but it seems like it would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builders typically get Tyvek in 9' rolls instead of 4' and 5' sheets. You may be able to buy a small piece off of the roll from your local building supply store or find some waste at a local construction site so that you don't have any seams to join.

If you do need to join two sheets of Tyvek, Tyvek Tape is specifically designed for sealing the joints when applied to a house. It's waterproof and adheres well. It's also quite strong, but similar to packing tape, once punctured it can tear easily.

[image: Tyvek Tape]

Comment: by "this" you mean the tyvek or the tape?

Comment: @RussellSteen, I was referring to the Tyvek itself and clarified my answer. 9' would be an awfully wide piece of tape. :)